# Xcode 6 : Linker error with Google Analytics

Tags: objective-c, google-analytics, ios8, xcode6

I'm currently getting this error

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from: 
objc-class-ref in libAdIdAccess.a(TAGActualAdIdAccess.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Added Frameworks:

- AdSupport
- CFNetwork
- libsqlite3.0.dylib
- libz.dylib
- libAdIdAccess.a
- libGoogleAnalticsServices.a

Tried evertyhing, also added -lAdIdAccess and -lGoogleAnalytics to other linker flag.

It happens with version 3.10 of the SDK.

Hope you can give me some advices to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

For implementing Google analytics you also have to import these two frameworks.

**SystemConfiguration.framework**

**CoreData.framework**

With **libsqlite3.0.dylib,libz.dylib,libGoogleAnalticsServices.a**

[A great tutorial on Google analytics](http://www.raywenderlich.com/53459/google-analytics-ios)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your target is linked with libGoogleConversionTracking.a. This may be a related library. I linked to this library to resolve this exact error.

Answer (score 0):

This answer arrives some years later but I just came across the same error as you.

I tried adding AdSupport.framework in the xcodeproj file for the target I am building under "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries". Adding that framework solved the error.

Source:
https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport